# Running Simulink Model that generates C/C++ code for compilation

Tags: c++, matlab, simulink, mex

While I am trying to run a simulink model the following error is encountered in relation with compilation and linking of C/C++ code

```
C:\Comms\slprj\_sfprj\quantizer_sim\_self\sfun\src>call "mexopts.bat"  

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. 

### Compiling "quantizer_sim_sfun.c" 
    cl.exe /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD   /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\include" /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\simulink\include" /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\stateflow\c\mex\include" /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\stateflow\c\debugger\include"  "quantizer_sim_sfun.c" 
quantizer_sim_sfun.c 
### Compiling "quantizer_sim_sfun_registry.c" 
    cl.exe /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD   /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\include" /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\simulink\include" /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\stateflow\c\mex\include" /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\stateflow\c\debugger\include"  "quantizer_sim_sfun_registry.c" 
quantizer_sim_sfun_registry.c 
### Compiling "c1_quantizer_sim.c" 
    cl.exe /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD   /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\include" /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\simulink\include" /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\stateflow\c\mex\include" /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\stateflow\c\debugger\include"  "c1_quantizer_sim.c" 
c1_quantizer_sim.c 
### Compiling "c2_quantizer_sim.c" 
    cl.exe /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD   /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\include" /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\simulink\include" /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\stateflow\c\mex\include" /I "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\stateflow\c\debugger\include"  "c2_quantizer_sim.c" 
c2_quantizer_sim.c 
### Linking ... 
    link.exe /nologo /dll /OPT:NOREF /export:mexFunction  /OUT:quantizer_sim_sfun.mexw64 /map:"quantizer_sim_sfun.map"  "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\stateflow\c\mex\lib\win64\sfc_mex.lib" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\stateflow\c\debugger\lib\win64\sfc_debug.lib"  "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\libmx.lib" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\libmex.lib" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\libmat.lib" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\libfixedpoint.lib" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\libut.lib" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\libmwmathutil.lib" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\libemlrt.lib" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\lib\win64\libippmwipt.lib"   "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\libmwblascompat32.lib" @quantizer_sim_sfun.mol 
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib' 
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\link.exe"' : return code '0x450' 
Stop. 



Error using quantizer_script (line 24)
Error using targetman>throw_make_error (line 588)
(SLSF Diagnostic)
```

Currently Matlab is configured with Visual Studio 2010 Compiler. In Addition I checked that the LIBPATH is correctly set from Matlab. I am also running Matlab with administator's permissions.

How can the `LINK` and `NMAKE` errors be solved?

Comment: Re-run `mex -setup`. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/gs/installing-stateflow-software.html#bqnop_7-5).

Comment: When I ran mex -setup, mex is locating Visual C++ 2010 compiler, however the following error is being encountered even while the SDK is installed in a seperate installation folder:

 Error: Could not find the 64-bit compiler.  This may indicate that the  
         "X64 Compilers and Tools" or the Microsoft Windows Software  
         Development Kit (SDK) is not installed.  To build 64-bit MEX-files  
         Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 requires that these two packages are  
         installed properly.

Comment: Visual C++ 2010 _Express_ or another edition?

Comment: Yes, the _Express_ edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Express editions are [no longer supported](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014a/index.html?sec=win64#simulink).

When you run `mex -setup` choose the SDK 7.1 ([download here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), select x64 compilers during installation).

Also be sure you install the [.NET Framework 4.0 runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851).

**Big however**: With the SDK, there is [a bug](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), where compilers get removed ([details from MS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2519277))!  Check it out [here too](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-G1P8HP/index.html?solution=1-G1P8HP).  The patch is on [Microsoft's website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4422).

See [this support article](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-FPLDGV/) for tips on how to download and configure the SDK for MATLAB.  Maybe confirm that the compilers were selected in the installation.